# Why does RDS login screen vary by user and PC?

Tags: windows-server-2008, rds, smartcard

I have two identical Lenovo laptops running Windows 10 with all updates. Call them Left and Right. On the backend I have a domain controller and a Remote Desktop Server, both running Windows Server 2008R2. I have two users, Bob and Alice, who log into the same domain and use the same remote desktop server. For both Bob and Alice on both Left and Right I have identical RDS configuration files. (I’m sure they’re identical because I copied the same file to all users and desktops.) When Alice logs in on Left and double-clicks on the RDS, I get [good login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJMk0.png), that is, I see smart card as a choice. But for Alice on Right and Bob on *either* laptop, a double-click on the RDS results in [bad login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0oiQ.png). What can be causing these two users/laptop to behave differently?

Comment: Does the file have an entry for `redirectsmartcards:i:1`?

Comment: @GregAskew: I was thinking that but I don't think that's it. What you're suggesting makes sense for the Right laptop but not the Left laptop if both users are using the same RDP file on each respective laptop. Alice does get it on the Left laptop but Bob doesn't get it on the Left laptop.

Comment: Comment from a similar question: "I realized that if I don't specify a username in the RDP connection and I use the IP address instead of the server's name, no smartcard is requested to login on the server."
http://superuser.com/questions/491344/when-rdp-as-a-domain-user-smart-card-requested

Comment: Yes, the RDP file has `redirectsmartcards:i:1` in it. Since all combinations use an identical RDS file, I can't imagine how anything in it can cause the variation I'm seeing.